# Is there a way to manage multiple redirect URI for different environments in the Instagram Developer website?

Tags: redirect, uri, instagram

I am wondering if there is a way to manage multiple redirect URI in the Instagram Developer website, for example with different environments.

On the Instagram developer center I have set the redirect URI as this for the dev environment.

```
http://localhost:3000/oauth/callback
```

But now I would like to push it to production, so I need to change this URI to the production one to get something like:

```
http://mywebsite/oauth/callback
```

but then I won't be able to get the correct redirection when I'm coding locally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best choice in my opinion would be to create two clients (apps) on Instagram:

- one for production
- one for dev

You will then have two sets of credentials.

For example with Rails switch from one config to the other depending on the current environment:

```
if Rails.env == "development" || Rails.env == "test"
  # load development instagram client config
else
  # load production instagram client config
end
```